# Rewrite SQL query using joins (or make it more efficient some other way)

Tags: sql, sqlite, join

Is it possible to rewrite the following SQL query using JOIN(s) or make it in other way more efficient ?
I may be using SQLite (I can connect to few different databases), which means I cannot use RIGHT JOIN(s). The ellipsis (...) in the query below means that I can have many UNION(s) there.

I construct this query programmatically, because there is no other way in my case. I'm just trying to get the idea how I could rewrite it to make it more efficient. Any ideas ?
Thanks in advance.

```
SELECT serial_nr, name, cert_type FROM certificates WHERE (cert_type<3 AND
serial_nr IN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT serial_nr FROM certificates WHERE (cert_type<3 AND (name LIKE 'george%' ))
    UNION
    SELECT DISTINCT serial_nr FROM ip_addresses WHERE ((address LIKE '192.168%' ))
    ....
));
```

Comment: I think you don't need those `DISTINCT`s ;).

Comment: That depends on the database schema, and on the selectivity of the subqueries and the overall query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this;

```
SELECT serial_nr, name, cert_type FROM certificates A 
inner join certificates B on A.serial_nr=B.serial_nr and B.name like'george%'
inner join ip_address C on A.serial_nr=C.serial_nr and C.Address like '192.168%'
...
WHERE A.cert_type<3
```

Comment: after a few modifications (changed inner join to left join) and added fully qualified names of tables - it worked! You did not precisely answered my question, but you pointed me to the right direction, so I'm going to accept your answer - thank you very much!